# Wrapping maps using EPSG:4326 in Leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, proj4js, proj4leaflet

I'm trying to use a tileserver in my leaflet app that encodes maps in EPSG:4326.

I understand that I need to use Proj4Leaflet, and I'm setting up my CRS as follows:

```
const crs = new Leaflet.Proj.CRS(
    'EPSG:4326',
    '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs',
    {
        resolutions: [
            0.3515625065578945,
            0.17578125327894775,
            0.08789062663947399,
            0.043945313319736994,
            0.021972656659868472,
            0.010986328329934226,
        ],
        origin: [-180, 90],
    }
);
```

But, when I do this, I just see the 1 earth (and get invalid tileserver requests like:
`tiles/bright_pc/1/-1/0.png`)

How can I wrap the map, like Leaflet does automatically for EPSG:3857?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining your own `EPSG:4326`, just use projection that is already available in Leaflet: `L.CRS.EPSG4326`.

See *Defined CRSs* section at https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#crs.